What is $\ker p_*$ of a resolution of rational singularity?
Let $X$ be a rational singularity over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Which means that there is a smooth variety (resolution of singularities of $X$) $Y$ with proper birational map $p \colon Y \to X$ such that $p_* \mathcal{O}_Y \cong \mathcal{O}_X$ and $R^ip_* \mathcal{O}_Y=0$ for $i>0$.
What (quasi-)coherent sheaves are in the kernel of the functor $p_*$? Can we describe them in some sense, or, at least, what are examples of such sheaves?

I’ve never heard of the kernel of a functor. Can you provide a definition or a reference?

Kernel of an additive functor is the full subcategory with all objects which this functor sends to an object isomorphic to the zero object.

This question is hard in general. One simple case is discussed in Theorem 5.2 of this paper https://epiga.episciences.org/12838.
